# Pass traffic from one network interface to another

Tags: networking, network-interface, proftpd, lighttpd

I have a project where I have 4x RPiZ plugged into a single RPi4. The RPiZs appear as Ethernet over USB devices as network interfaces `ethpi1`, `ethpi2`, `ethpi3`, and `ethpi4` with IP addresses `10.0.11.2`, `10.0.12.2`, `10.0.13.2`, and `10.0.14.2` respectively. The RPi4 is on a network I have access to with a known, but not controlled, IP address like `192.168.0.2` or something. I won't have physical access to the device once it is set up. All 5x RPi's have a FTP (proftpd) server, a HTTP (lighttpd) server, and SSH enabled.

I am trying to figure out how to access these servers on the RPiZ's without first SSHing into the RPi4. This involves multiple related questions. If I have a computer on the same ethernet network as the RPi4, how do I direct traffic to/from the RPiZ's?

Comment: You configure the RPi4 as a router. It should be sufficient to set `ip_forward` to 1 to achieve that. A packet with destination 10.0.11.2 that enters the RPi4's eth0 interface (or whatever the main Ethernet interface is named) will be routed to ethpi1. Then, create routing entries on the client so that traffic to 10.0.{11..14}.2 goes to the RPi4.

Answer (score 0):

I got it from another source. I asked the same question on the raspberry pi stack exchange. Here is the answer.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120387/pass-traffic-from-one-network-interface-to-another/120398#120398

Run this on the RPi4

```
rpi4b ~$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Run this on the computer trying to access the subnet.

```
osx ~$ sudo route add 10.0.0/24.0/24 192.168.0.2
```